# Flask Response returning escape character

Tags: python, json, mongodb, dictionary, flask

This is my code for querying via mongo-engine and returning response

```
comments = []
answers = []
question = Question.objects.get(id=id).to_json()
comments.append(Comments.objects.filter(question=id).to_json())
answers.append(Answers.objects.filter(question=id).to_json())
content = {"question": question, "comments": comments, "answers": answers}
print(content)
return Response(content, mimetype='application/json', status=200)
```

This is printing correctly:

```
{
  'question': '{"_id": {"$oid": "5efb9f3ef0612bfe7862b63c"}, "heading": "what is Doubt-bag?"}',
  'comments': [
    '[{"_id": {"$oid": "5efba1c5a4bd7de54890a7c9"}, "comment": "This is a very good question"}, {"_id": {"$oid": "5efba3ea402375df5fe9484a"}, "comment": "This is a very good question-1(duplicate)", }]'
  ],
  'answers': [
    '[{"_id": {"$oid": "5efba1c9a4bd7de54890a7ca"}, "answer": "This is a store house of all doubts people can have ranging to different topic."}, {"_id": {"$oid": "5efba408402375df5fe9484b"}, "answer": "This is a store house of all doubts people can have ranging to different topic.(duplicate)"}]'
  ]
}
```

But through Response, it gives:

```
{
    "question": "{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5efb9f3ef0612bfe7862b63c\"}, \"heading\": \"what is Doubt-bag?\"}",
    "comments": [
        "[{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5efba1c5a4bd7de54890a7c9\"}, \"comment\": \"This is a very good question\"}, {\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5efba3ea402375df5fe9484a\"}, \"comment\": \"This is a very good question-1(duplicate)\"}]"
    ],
    "answers": [
        "[{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5efba1c9a4bd7de54890a7ca\"}, \"answer\": \"This is a store house of all doubts people can have ranging to different topic.\"}, {\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5efba408402375df5fe9484b\"}, \"answer\": \"This is a store house of all doubts people can have ranging to different topic.(duplicate)\"}]"
    ]
}
```

I have tried almost all the solutions in StackOverflow like doing json.dumps or passing content directly while sending responses but all are giving exactly the same results. Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem!

```
content = {'question': json.loads(Question.objects.filter(id=id).to_json()),
                       'comments': json.loads(Comments.objects.filter(question=id).to_json()),
                       'answers': json.loads(Answers.objects.filter(question=id).to_json())}
return content
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your intent is to embed JSON in JSON, that doesn't look correct.

The escaping issue you're seeing is downstream of that issue. When you `print(content)`, Python is free to print strings with whatever quotes it chooses, and it chooses single quotes.

That form of `Response` builds JSON under the covers. The JSON specification calls for double quotes.

By the way, with the lastest Flask, it suffices to

```
return content
```

You'll get a 200 status and an "application/json" mime type for free.

Comment: even after using  'return content', I am getting the same Response with the escape characters. Is there any other way around I can do?